# Getting object array list from global Array with TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

Given a global array that contains:

```js
{
  id: 1,
  name: test,
  age: 23,
  toys: [
    { id: 2, label: mouse },
    { id: 1, label: house },
    { id: 4, label: car }
  ]
}
```

I want to extract just array of toy of a given kid `id` using ES6 TypeScript

I've tried:

```
this.toys = this.kids.find(kid => kid.id === KidId);
```

Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to use a filter() ? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter. The find method you used only gets one result

Comment: Yes i wanna filter results but return just toys array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to call `.toys`:

```js
this.toys = this.kids.find(kid => kid.id === KidId).toys;
```